# Automatically increase number of columns as width increases

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

Is anyone aware of a good way to display input across a changing number of columns as the width of the screen increases/decreases? Say, for example, I have 15 people. If your screen is 1200 pixels wide, I want to give you the 15 people in 3 columns of 5 people each. If your screen is between 800 and 1200 pixels wide, then I want to give you 2 columns of 7 and 8, and anything smaller than 800 pixels, I would just give you a single list of 15 people.

I am looking for a jQuery or angularJS solution.

Comment: The the width and height is same for each "person" why don't you simply float them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use CSS3 `columns` properties in conjunction with media queries to change them

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: best suggestion is google for it...here's MDN docs...explains all the properties with some examples  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this with angularjs or javascript in general as listening to the resize-event is quite costly. Why not use css-media queries?

```
@media(min-width: 1200px){
   td:nth-child(13+n){
     display: none;
   } 
   tr:nth-child(4+n){
     display: none;
   } 
}
@media(min-width: 800ox){
   td:nth-child(8+n){
     display: none;
   } 
   tr:nth-child(3+n){
     display: none;
   } 
}
```

If you really want to, you can use something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/GpLHZ/

although a directive linked to the specific controller handling the data or a directive for the table might be a better approach.